# How to remove the zip code field from the checkout page?

Tags: 8, commerce

I have a Drupal 8 website with Drupal Commerce 2.x. I want to disable the zip code field in the checkout page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Address modifications should be done on the Address module level, not on the Commerce level.

You can disable the zip code for a specific country by subscribing to the AddressFormatEvent and removing the %postalCode token from the $definition['format'] string. A str_replace('%postalCode', '', $definition['format']) should do it.

You can find an example event in [this blog post.](http://timonweb.com/posts/set-required-and-optional-address-inputs-for-address-field-in-drupal-8/)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which checkout pane you want to remove it from.

1. If you want to remove it from the shipping address, you will need to create a custom form widget for the address module.
2. If you want to remove it from the billing address, you would need to extend the `PaymentGateway` Commerce plugin and the `PaymentMethodAddForm` PluginForm.

Below are examples using Stripe and removing the postal_code from the billing address. As far as I know, you would never want to do this.

Example Stripe override: `example\Plugin\Commerce\PaymentGateway\ExampleStripe.php`

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\example\Plugin\Commerce\PaymentGateway;

use Drupal\commerce_stripe\Plugin\Commerce\PaymentGateway\Stripe;

/**
 * Provides the Example customized Stripe payment gateway.
 *
 * @CommercePaymentGateway(
 *   id = "example_stripe",
 *   label = "Example Stripe",
 *   display_label = "Example Stripe",
 *   forms = {
 *     "add-payment-method" = "Drupal\example\PluginForm\example\PaymentMethodAddForm",
 *   },
 *   payment_method_types = {"credit_card"},
 *   credit_card_types = {
 *     "amex", "dinersclub", "discover", "jcb", "maestro", "mastercard", "visa",
 *   },
 * )
 */
class ExampleStripe extends Stripe {

}
```

And then the example PaymentMethodAddForm override:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\example\PluginForm\ExampleStripe;

use Drupal\commerce_stripe\PluginForm\Stripe\PaymentMethodAddForm as StripePaymentMethodAddForm;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Class PaymentMethodAddForm.
 *
 * Removing the postal code from billing address.
 *
 * @package Drupal\example\PluginForm\ExampleStripe
 */
class ExamplePaymentMethodAddForm extends StripePaymentMethodAddForm {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::buildConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);

    /** @var \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order $order */
    if ($order = $this->routeMatch->getParameter('commerce_order')) {
      // Not recommended.
      $form['billing_information']['field_address']['postal_code']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
    return $form;
  }

}
```

Finally, you would need to go into the Payment Gateway configuration page and select or create a new payment gateway using your new version of the plugin.

Comment: Hi sir, I want to remove it from billing address and shipping address too. And I have only payment gateway is Cash On Delivery. I do not want other payment gateways.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and simplest way is to add an after build function to the address element. In this the whole element will be built and allow you to remove access to the postal code element.

Remember to use `['#access'] = FALSE` and provide a default value. Otherwise there could be unknown validation issues

Comment: Hi sir @Matt Glaman, I don't know how to build function and where to put it. Please could you more specific because I am new and don't know code much.